# Processing large amounts of data in AngularJS coming from Codeigniter Restful API?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm currently novice in both PHP and AngularJS (although my main focus is AngularJS), anyways I picked up an open source music project(uses Codeigniter) I found online, just for learning purposes. The project basically is setup to have a user sign up , upload music and then have it display on their profile, as well as a section where you can browse through everyone's music.

So I've built/been-building an angularJS app from this project using the API library that came with the project. I pretty much got everything working, loading users information, displaying/playing the music in all the correct views, etc.

There's just one problem with the AngularJS based APP, I've been striving to find a solution for. The API that retrieves everyones music for the "discover" section, sends ALL of it from the database. At first I didnt notice the problem because I only had two ficticious users signed up, with a total of 20 songs, so the discovery section did not take to long to load. But upon futher testing, I decided to replicate more users, for a total 500 users and a total of 1000 songs. This is where I noticed a huge difference in load time.

So basically my question is what would be the recommended approach to handle this? Is there a way in AngularJS to limit the amount of data it reads in at a time? (for example, only load 20 songs initially then load 20 more after clicking "View more") or is this something that should be handled by PHP?

Here is the simple API function that was predefined in this project.

```
    function discovery_get(){
    $result = $this->db->query("select * from user_songs ORDER BY song_views DESC")->result();
    $this->response($result, 200);
}
```

Example snippet how api is called:

```
$http.jsonp('http://myapi.dev/api/discovery/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (data) {
    $scope.discovery = data.data;
    //console.log(data);
   // some more code here....
});
```

Thank you for any responses, and I apologize in advance if my question is all over the place. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When data is large one needs to page data from the server. The client then needs to make request for data on a per page basis.

On the Angular side you can show pager in case you use grid or use something like [infinite scoll plugin](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) that loads data as data gets scrolled into the view.

Comment: Thank you for this post! Got my brain thinking last night, and whipped something up!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to @Chandermani, who got my brain thinking with his answer.

So I modified my API to take in parameters (probably not the best way to do it, but im a newbie) These parameters are dynamically generated inside of angularjs.

```
    function discover_get(){
    $offset = $this->get('offset');
    $songs =$this->get('songs');
    $artists = $this->db->query("select * from user_songs ORDER BY song_views LIMIT $offset, $songs")->result();

    $result = array(
        "test" => "awesome",
        "artists" => $artists
        );

    $this->response($result, 200);
}
```

I created a controller which has a "`discovery`" service which calls the api, and then inside the controller I have another function called "`loadmore()`" which calls the api again, with a new offset that way the old data doesn't get repeated again. I also took Chandermani's advance and used the infinite scroll which calls the "`loadmore()`" which just makes it easier than having a `ng-click`

```
controllers.controller('DiscoverCtrl' , function ($scope, discovery, $http) {
$scope.discover;
var offset = 0;
var songs = 2;
discovery.list(offset, songs).then(function (data) {
    $scope.discover = data.data;
    console.log(data);
});



$scope.loadmore = function () {
offset += 2;
discovery.list(offset, songs).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
$scope.discover.artists = $scope.discover.artists.concat(data.data.artists);
//$scope.discover = data.data




});


};
```